# Triple integration: clarification on a problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, volume

I would like some clarification on the provided answer to a problem.

I'm performing the following calculation: 
$$\iiint_{D}(x^2+y)z \;dx\,dy\,dz$$
for $D :=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R: 0 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $ 0 \leq z \leq 1\}$.

I'm using the substitution
$$ (x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, z)$$ for $D' :=\{0\leq r \leq 1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1\}$

this gives me $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} rz(r^{2}cos^{2}\theta+rsin\theta)\;dr\,d\theta \,dz$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} z(r^{3}cos^{2}\theta+r^{2}sin \theta)\; dr\,d\theta \,dz = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

in the answers however they drop the $z$ getting

$$\int_{0}^{1}dz\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} (r^{3}cos^{2}\theta+r^{2}sin \theta)\;dr\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

I'm missing their rationale on why to drop the z variable, the Jacobian associated equals $r$ any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look kosher to me.  I can see how you get from $\iiint (r^3\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin\theta)z\ dz \ dr\ d\theta$ to $\int z\ dz\iint (r^3\cos^2\theta + r^2\sin\theta)\ dr \ d\theta$ but that is not your problem.  You can't just drop the $z.$ entirely.

Comment: i agree entirely, and in all honesty the moderator(marker) may have made a simple mistake when dropping the z but i thought it better to ask the great minds of maths stack exchange.

Comment: It seems that you are right. We cannot drop $z$ !

Comment: i'm thinking ive made a mistake with one of the limits somewhere,